# Generic type nullable and ToString

Tags: c#, generics, nullable, tostring

In my method I want to process nullable integer values.

```
public String FormatValue(Int32? item)
{
 if (item.HasValue==false) return "";
 return item.Value.ToString("### ### ###");
}
```

We do no want to write `Int32?`, `Int64?` and other versions from this method, so we wanted to refactor it to handle generic type parameters:

```
public String FormatValue<T>(T item)
{
 if (item.HasValue==false) return ""; // ERROR: no .HasValue property
 return item.Value.ToString("### ### ###"); // ERROR: usually has no ToString() with string argument
}
```

How should I handle this situation? I tried to use the `"where T"` clause, but without any success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you only want your method for nullable types, there doesn't seem to be a problem in having `T?` as a parameter instead of `T`. You can then constrain `T`: it has to implement `IFormattable`, which the basic integer types do implement.

```
public string FormatValue<T>(T? item) where T : struct, IFormattable
{
  if (item == null) return "";
  return item.Value.ToString("### ### ###", null);
}
```

Comment: That's everything what I wanted :) THX!

Answer (score 5):

First of all:

```
public String FormatValue<T>(Nullable<T> item)
     where T : struct, IFormattable
{
   if (item.HasValue==false) return ""; 
   return item.Value.ToString("### ### ###", null /* you format provider */ );
}
```

You are passing generic `T` as parameter, but you need `Nullable`.

Secondly:
`ToString()` in `Nullable` is already doing what you need - you don't have to do it manually (this is in case, when you don't have to format):

```
int? a = null;
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString()); // outputs "", no any exception
```

Comment: No, my anwser where also posted in a very similar time to you. I always test solutions after posting (when I'm not sure) and then correct errors. It's the only solution for problem, so don't be mad the it's the same (and had similar errors) and don't offence me.

Comment: @hvd he was even a little bit faster than you and his null check was different than yours. I don't think it's a copy.

Comment: If you had included a correct version, I would have indeed assumed that you came up with it independently, but having the same error in two independent answers is generally very unlikely. But if others seem to think it is likely here, then I guess I'll give you the benefit of the doubt. (BTW, the edit history doesn't show changes made in the first five minutes after posting, and this answer has been changed in those first five minutes. In cases like this, it would have been useful to have them visible.)

Answer (score 2):

Try to define the method's argument as `Nullable<T>`:

```
public String FormatValue<T>(Nullable<T> item) where T : struct
{
    return item.HasValue ? item.Value.ToString("### ### ###") : String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: `T` must be a struct in order to pass generic `nullable`.

Comment: @pwas, Thank you. I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `IFormattable` is probably the best idea, but you can also use `string.Format`:

```
public string FormatValue<T>(T? item) where T : struct
{
  return string.Format("{0:### ### ###}", item);
}
```